# What happens if a communication partner changes his IP within a tcp connection

Tags: rest, http, mobile, soap, tcp

I'm thinking of a mobile client based on Phonegap that communicates via a REST and SOAP interface with a server. The communication is stateless and happens over TCP. The client only makes a request and gets a response from the server directly via HTTP. I have two questions about that situation:

1. What happens if the mobile client switches networks e.g. from WLAN to GPRS and thereby its ip changes while the request/answer is being transmitted? Will tcp handle this?
2. Are there any other problems I'm currently not thinking about that can be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

If the IP address changes, any existing TCP connection(s) must be closed and re-connected.  Since HTTP itself is typically state-less and not tied to any particular connection, it has its own mechanisms (cookies, sessions) for persisting data/state information across multiple requests as needed, as it is not uncommon for HTTP clients to drop connections between requests to the same server.

Comment: If you include [this](http://serverfault.com/a/604574/98187) and the identification of connection via (dest ip+port, src ip+port) (like [here](http://serverfault.com/a/61960/98187)) in your answer you will get the mark. :)

Comment: RFC 6824 is experimental, not a standard. It states as much in its category and memo status. And since only a few known implementations exist, you cannot rely on it for widespread use yet.